# Form inside another form with same inputs

Tags: php, forms, variables

Is there a way to send exactly same variables to another page different from action of the form? I tried this structure but the second submit button did not work;

```
<form name="2" action="page2" method="post" >

<form name="1" action="page1" method="post" >

<input type="radio" name="radio" value="value1" >
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="value2" >
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="value3" >

<input type="submit" value="Submit1">

</form>

<input type="submit" value="Submit2">

</form>
```

The form 1 shows the information of inputs on the page1 and updates database also.

I want form 2 to show the information of inputs on the page2 only (no update of database).

Is that possible?

Comment: You can have a single `<form>` tag with multiple submit buttons. That sounds like it'd do what you're trying to do

Comment: Use one form with one submit and once you have received the post in your php you "repost" it using curl. Here an example doing about the same.... http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have form inside another form , change your code like this.

```
<form name="2" action="page2" method="post" >
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="value1" >
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="value2" >
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="value3" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit1" name="submit1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit2" name="submit2">
</form>
```

Give different name for each submit button.

in php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    // submit1 is pressed
}

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    // submit2 is pressed
}
```

Changing action dynamically.

add class to submit buttons say, class="submit". ANd add id to form say id="my-form"

```
$(".submit").change(function() {
      var action = $(this).val() == "submit1" ? "submit1.php : "submit2.php";
     $("#my-form").attr("action",  action);
});
```

Comment: How can i set different action page for the second submit?

Comment: in php, you can do what you want. or use javascript for that

Comment: Thank you. I will try it as soon as I arrive home.

Comment: actually I couldn't try that. Because I saw that the form was already doesn't have any action. I wanted to add the second for to woocommerce "form-pay.php" file but it's form is: <form id="order_review" method="post"> and no action url.

Comment: you can add any action you want there. In script, we change the actin dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer firstly. It should already have an action in maybe woocommerce hooks or javascript. I tried to find it but nothing found. What I try to achive is that; woocommerce sends an email to customer about products he bought, prices, totals, quantities, and method of payment after he made the payment. I want to show him this same data including payment method, just before the payment done. So I need to send this data which is in the order payment page to a new page to show him without saving to database. I tried many thing then I wanted to try double form.

Comment: no need of double form bro, you can add what ever you want in same form, on click of submit button u ll get to no which button in clicked, so based on button click, perform the action.

Comment: Can you please check the image below? [link](http://i.hizliresim.com/Ag7rAr.png) the payment_method is sending to thank you page with this payment button. But I can't send same data to aggrement page after clicking on agg. link. I thought it could be done by moving this aggrement link in the form or payment, maybe the method is wrong but I tried many things.

Comment: @NranjanNRaju No, it is already like that. User can not make paymet without checking it. But if user clicks to that link near the check box, it opens an aggrement page. He should see in this page the informaiton mentioned. I need to pass this data to that link.

Comment: if its troubling you so much, use popup to display the data or use `<a>` tag.

Comment: @NranjanNRaju I couldn't explain it clearly. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: @BerkKoç in any way, if answer had helped you, accept the answer.